# How to cross-compile the criu for arm64( Raspberry pi ) ? from: https://criu.org/ARM_crosscompile

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, cross-compilation, arm64

[image]

I tried the commands from: https://criu.org/ARM_crosscompile site, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where is the source code tarball? What is the CPU architecture of build machine? What is the distribution of the build machine? Did you try `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` in Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: Yes, I installed gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu too. but didn't help

Comment: @Biswapriyo
This is my kernel version: 5.3.0-1014-raspi2
And my build machine details are as follows:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan